# Define a collection's model type in Backbone using Typescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

I'm trying to use Backbone with Typescript, and I'm not following Typescript's syntax for how to define which type of model a collection will hold.

```
module Application.Collections {
    export class Library extends Backbone.Collection {
        model = Application.Models.Book; // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
        constructor(options?) {
            super(options);
        };
    }
}

module Application.Models {
    export class Bookextends Backbone.Model {
        constructor(options?) {
            super(options);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Type of overridden member 'model' is not subtype of original
member defined by type 'Collection';
```

It's also not clear to me when I should put definitions like this in the constructor, or whether it matters. I tried:

```
constructor(options?) {
        super(options);
        this.model = Application.Models.Entity;
};
```

Which says:

```
Cannot convert 'new(options?:any) => Models.Template' to 'Backbone.Model'
```

What I'm really trying to do is define a model type that has a few utility methods - when the basic model data is fetched from the server, I want the model to initialize and calculate a few convenience properties based on the server data. But this isn't happening, because the collection.fetch() doesn't think the return model is of any specific type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the model before "super(options);"

```
    module Application.Models {
         export class Book extends Backbone.Model {
         constructor(options?) {
             super(options);
         }
    }    

    module Application.Collections {
        export class Library extends Backbone.Collection {

            constructor(options?) {
                this.model = Application.Models.Book;
                super(options);
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for TypeScript >= 1.8 since "'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class." to quote the error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type that variable, you would use:

```
model: Application.Models.Book;
```

If you want the class name at runtime, you can either use a string, or [this method of obtaining the class name at runtime](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201304/Blog/Obtaining-A-Class-Name-At-Runtime-In-TypeScript/).

```
model = 'Application.Models.Book';
```

Or

```
model = Describer.getName(someObject);
```

There is a limit on this second method that you only get the class name, not the full path.

Comment: Sweet : http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201304/Blog/Obtaining-A-Class-Name-At-Runtime-In-TypeScript/ +1