# Does not Backbone fetch call constructors for retrieved models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

It seems that neither Backbone collection `fetch` nor `parse` functions call constructor for the retrieved models; am I right? So if one needs to initialize some special properties for them (in constructor or initializer), he must call it explicitly. E. g., in `success` callback of the `fetch` function. Or may be I miss something?

Example follows.

```
return t.collection.fetch({
    success: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < t.collection.models.length; i++) {
            t.collection.models[i] = new MyModel(t.collection.models[i]);
        }
    },
});
```

Here the `t.collection` is of type

```
class MyModelsCollection extends Backbone.Collection<MyModel> {
    url = "/api/MyModels/";
}
```

The TypeScript has been used.

**Solution**. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947537/1561966) made me to check the TypeScript syntax used here. I have found that it was incorrect. It must be like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17152593/1561966) (except that the `super()` call should go first). So one should set the `model` property of the collection manually in the constructor.

May be it was obvious for everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just link your model class to [`model` option](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) of the collection, everything will work by itself.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Colleciton.extend({
    url: "/api/MyModels/",
    model: MyModel
});
```

When instance of `MyCollection` will be fetched and there will be an array of models from backend, it will create needed amount of MyModel instances.

Comment: Your answer is obviously correct for pure JavaScript and it made me to check the TypeScript syntax for this case. I am going to include the information I have investigated in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I found this [TodoMVC example](http://todomvc.com/examples/typescript-backbone/) in TypeScript with Backbone, may be it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it contains a couple of interesting things.